# How to get the elements of an XML tag in a String using Java?

Tags: java, xml

I am new to XML parsing. I have the following sample XML:

```
<ErrorDetail><Error>Invalid cob date/FeedID </Error><InvalidColumn>FeesCom</InvalidColumn><InvalidColumn>Provis</InvalidColumn><InvalidColumn></InvalidColumn></ErrorDetail>
```

I need a Java code which gives me the contents of `ErrorDetail` tag in a String. Something which looks like:

```
String xmlString = "<Error>Invalid cob date/FeedID </Error><InvalidColumn>FeesCom</InvalidColumn><InvalidColumn>Provis</InvalidColumn><InvalidColumn></InvalidColumn>";
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: I tried to use the basic parsing methods, but all are giving me the value of the tags. But what I need is a string with the child tags and their values in it.

Comment: Without more context, it's hard to know what you want to do exactly. I would suggest reading up on JAXP and specifically XPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code gave me the child elements without manually taking the sub-string.

```
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("ErrorDetail").item(0).getChildNodes();
DOMSource source = null;
for (int x = 0; x < nl.getLength(); x++) {
   Node e = nl.item(x);
   if (e instanceof Element) {
     source = new DOMSource(e);
     transformer.transform(source, result);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I got it correctly, but I think with JDOM (2.0.2) this is quite simple...

```
String xml = "<ErrorDetail><Error>Invalid cob date/FeedID </Error><InvalidColumn>FeesCom</InvalidColumn><InvalidColumn>Provis</InvalidColumn><InvalidColumn></InvalidColumn></ErrorDetail>";
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8"));
Document doc = new SAXBuilder().build(stream);

System.out.println(new XMLOutputter().outputString(doc.getRootElement().getContent()));
```

... gives me the following output:

```
<Error>Invalid cob date/FeedID </Error><InvalidColumn>FeesCom</InvalidColumn><InvalidColumn>Provis</InvalidColumn><InvalidColumn />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what my requirement is, I have a main XML where ErrorDetails come as a sub tag of the main XML and ErrorDetail has  other sub tags within it. When I'm parsing it using JAXB, I'm getting ErrorDetail as a java class. What I need is, conents of the ErrorDetail tag as a String. In the given answer, you have considered the XML as a String I guess. In that case, I have to first convert my generated java class into XML and then to a String. Is that right ?

Comment: @SuchithraUS could you update your _question_ with this information. Asking half a question is likely to get you half an answer. Please post your **full** question - preferably with an illustrative example.

Comment: I totally agree with @BoristheSpider, your recent comment adds useful information to the question. I think this example http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xmlanyelement-and-non-dom-properties.html will help you... There they get the bio-tag out of the customer as a string using the JAXB XmlAnyElement annotation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're relying on a stable xml-structure, you could use this example:

```
public static String getErrorDetailsContent(String s) {
    int start = s.indexOf("<Error>");
    if (start == -1)
        // throw some exc
    int end = s.lastIndexOf("</InvalidColumn>");
    if (end == -1)
        // throw some exc
    return s.substring(start, end);
}
```